# Is there anyway to do nested Pick<> types in Typescript

Tags: typescript, graphql

So I am trying to get safety on my client side GraphQL queries (so if there is a better approach to this let me know).

But what I have been doing is defining my query like this.

```
export const tenantManagePageQuery = async (tenantId: string) =>
    graphQLClient.request<{
        tenants: TenantManagePageQueryTenant[];
    }>(
        /* GraphQL */ `
            query tenants($tenantId: String!) {
                tenants(tenantIds: [$tenantId]) {
                    id
                    description
                    name
                    approvedUsers {
                        id
                        alias
                    }
                    pendingUsers {
                        id
                        alias
                    }
                }
            }
        `,
        { tenantId },
    );
```

in order to define the `TenantManagePageQueryTenant` type I do something like this

```
interface TenantManagePageQueryTenant
    extends Pick<Tenant, 'id' | 'description' | 'name'> {}
```

Where the base Tenant model is my GQL model type.

Is there anyway to do this kind of Pick statement but to also pick the nested properties.

something like

```
interface TenantManagePageQueryTenant
    extends Pick<Tenant, 'id' | 'description' | 'name' | Pick<approvedUser| 'id' | 'alias'> {}
```

Comment: What's the use case? You want a type union of all possible keys (even if nested under another key?)

Comment: I want to Pick a field of the root type, but ensure that the keys in that field are all valid keys of some other type

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Similar to Colins answer, but coming at it from the opposite direction. If you have an existing interface/type you need to pick apart you can use indexes:

```
// Existing type
type Tenant = {
    id:string;
    description:string;
    name:string;
    approvedUsers: Array<{
      id:string;
      alias:string;
    }>
}

// Pick it apart
type TenantManagePageQueryTenant = 
  Pick<Tenant, 'id' | 'description' | 'name'> & {
    approvedUsers: Array<Pick<Tenant['approvedUsers'][0], 'id' | 'alias'>>
  }
```

### Alternative 1 - Extracted types

As noted in the comments, this can be slightly cleaner:

```
type TenantSubset = Pick<Tenant, 'id' | 'description' | 'name'>
type ApprovedUserSubset = Pick<Tenant['approvedUsers'][number], 'id' | 'alias'>

type TenantManagePageQueryTenant = TenantSubset & { approvedUsers: Array<ApprovedUserSubset> }
```

### Alternative 2 - Pick-less pick

This version, while a little more repetitive, is (subjectively) easier to read:

```
type TenantManagePageQueryTenant = { 
  id: Tenant['id'],
  description: Tenant['description'],
  name: Tenant['name'],
  approvedUsers: Array<{
    id: Tenant['approvedUsers'][number]['id'],
    alias: Tenant['approvedUsers'][number]['alias'],
  }> 
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=25&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhB2BDewoF4oG8CwAoKBUAlgCYBcAzsAE5HwDmA3HoVCRBQMa1jBED28SjTpMWhJAFsIw2g2b5CiMGGr8AbhBIBVChGoUyUAILVqiEAB4ci1qVmiFrAogA2RRIapyxtqAF8APjx-PDxQSFgEZGAAWWREeggABUSIAEUAV30QOCQUdChxZKJOAGtLPJiAGigAclI6qAAfevYuHj5BJta6qQg6wKgAMixxFxU1TR09AyNTcysS8srolABtOuVVDS1dfQo6gF11gAYj2oaSHvq3D0PA4MVQ3DDcVwhUYDXgMiqUeJIJKpJJZHL-VAYGwEexQABEAEYAEwAZjh1XE7W4RF4AiE8IALABWABs6PE-SMcIA7AAOACc5MU2yme1mhig62hhFhcMQ-KZrDunipACNxXDxP4jiEgA)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted Thanks alot

Comment: I generally like typescript but it's looking at types like these when I feel that I should look into other languages, cause surely stuff like this cannot be the norm?

Comment: @IvanP I think the "norm" depends on your codebase. I would say _most_ of the projects I work keep the types more simple than this. I've also worked on types that are more complex, especially for libraries. Take a look at the type definitions of some popular libraries like React, it gets hairy. At the end of the day, only you (and your team) can decide if the complexity provides value. I would also say the above could be cleaned up, extract out an ApprovedUser type, etc but the question was aimed at nested picks

Comment: this is super messy and will be unusable for some data types

Comment: @ICW The question asks for a nested pick - while the answer may not be the "cleanest", TypeScript doesn't lend to anything better in its current form. As mentioned in the comment above, it could be cleaned up by abstracting types, and its probably not something I would use in my own projects but it answers the question.

Comment: @ICW I've added two alternatives, thoughts?

Answer (score 14):

The code posted by @Avius is on the right track, but the interface extending the intersection type generates an error. I believe you'd need to use type:

```
type TenantManagePageQueryTenant = Pick<Tenant, 'id' | 'description' | 'name'>
    & { approvedUsers: Pick<ApprovedUser, 'id' | 'alias'>[] }
{ }

interface Tenant {
    id:string;
    description:string;
    name:string;
}

interface ApprovedUser {
    id:string;
    alias:string;
}

let tenant:TenantManagePageQueryTenant = {
  id: "123",
  description: "456",
  name: "789",
  approvedUsers: [{
    id: "aaa",
    alias: "bbb" // To see the desired type warning, try removing 'alias' 
  }]
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhB2BDewCyzEHMIAUsQEUBXCAJxDiRSgF4ocBLAYwGsAeS5YAGigHIGAEz5QAPv0EQAzk1IMwwBgHt4I8XyQBbCHwB8AWABQUE1ABkUAN5REYMKSUA3CIICqUslIBc9ZuwCCdg7Obh6kvALCYvyIADYMiFJ6ANoAulAAvkbWWYZGDChkAGaITNCc1JZGplBCXlLAcvCYANzVppIycgrK8PWNBa3tJloQ-U1Dhrn5haQlZVCB9k4u7mRWw7WC44NtxqZxCd4NE3vThrEQwFDACFxeFWgY2HjYxGQUd9R0Vft1UAAiACMACYAMwA7jtTqyeSKFQ%20AEAFgArAA2SHtUaIgDsAA4AJyY-a2ZYhNakbxQZK-Gr-AGIRnEmqHRKIgBGnIB7QyqSMGSAA)

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if i understood the question correctly but perhaps *intersection types* would help?

Assuming that `approvedUsers` is actually an array, the type might look something like this:

```
interface TenantManagePageQueryTenant extends
    Pick<Tenant, 'id' | 'description' | 'name'>
    & { approvedUsers: Pick<ApprovedUser | 'id' | 'alias'>[] }
{}
```

Thus this would be a valid object of type `TenantManagePageQueryTenant`:

```
{
  id: "123",
  description: "456",
  name: "789",
  approvedUsers: [{
    id: "aaa",
    alias: "bbb"
  }]
}
```

Whereas these would not:

```
// missing alias in approvedUsers[0]

{
  id: "123",
  description: "456",
  name: "789",
  approvedUsers: [{
    id: "aaa"
  }]
}
```

```
// unknown field extra in approvedUsers[0]
{
  id: "123",
  description: "456",
  name: "789",
  approvedUsers: [{
    id: "aaa",
    alias: "bbb",
    extra: 345678
  }]
}
```